# How to implement Multiple Parties logic in Corda

Tags: java, corda

1. How to implement Parties list in Corda and how can Party List be Persisted in DB?
2. Is storing a Party list( `List<AbstractParty>` ) is advisable in JPA ?

I tried to have `List<AbstractParty>` and which is returned in `getParticipant()` and while persisting it using Schema, we used `.toString` with the list and persisted as a string.

Can you suggest how to implement multiple parties dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Party in Corda represents the distributed identity on the Network. It is normally managed on the network level by the Identity Manager (which is owned by the network operator). You can get a list of the Parties whenever you request a networkMap. You don't necessarily need to store them by yourself.

More details can be found: https://docs.corda.net/api-identity.html

Comment: Thanks @Peter, In State, we would mention the parties involved in the transactions and those parties are returned in the `getParticipants` function in the State. How do I persist the party list in the database, how to implement the Schema for it?. Is storing `List<Party>` in single column advisable ?